# Comparing LEGO® MINDSTORMS® Education EV3 Core Set with LEGO MINDSTORMS EV3 Toy Robot Building Kit - 31313

Tags: sets, set-database

LEGO® MINDSTORMS® Education EV3 Core Set is described briefly here EV3 [Core Set](https://shop.creative-hut.com/collections/all/products/lego%C2%AE-mindstorms%C2%AE-education-ev3-core-set)

LEGO MINDSTORMS EV3 Toy Robot Building Kit - 31313 is described here [Robot Building Set](https://www.argos.co.uk/product/7242029)

---

As an adult who wants to experiment with robotics, I am interested in purchasing one or other of these. I want to compare what is in these sets in terms of components and relate that to price.

Despite having plenty of experience with online search generally, I'm having trouble doing a part-for-part comparison.  I have tried searching Bricklink but can only find entries for individual parts rather than  a complete parts list.

**Question**

I am not asking for someone to do all the work for me (although I wouldn't refuse!), I'd just like some guidance on how to find a complete list of parts for each of these sets - maybe a simple link to each.

Comment: You might also consider moving to the new boost platform. There is the Spike Prime set and later this year a robotics set similar to Spike Prime will be released. EV3 is being phased out (on the other hand, it can now be found at greatly reduced price) ...

Comment: @Michael Verschaeve - Ouch! When I started this area of enquiry I though that LEGO was LEGO and that was it. Little did I realise that so much change goes on. I'll investigate Spike Prime but I fear by the time I have caught up with that my knowledge will be out-of-date again!

Answer (score 2):

Here is a parts list for  the CORE SET: https://brickset.com/sets/45544-1/Education-EV3-Core-Set

And here is a parts list for the Toy Robot Building Kit: https://brickset.com/sets/31313-1/Mindstorms-EV3

In the future, there is a good chance that Brickset has an inventory!

Answer (score 1):

A year or two ago I got Mindstorms 31313, but I wanted to be able to build the models from the Education Core set too, so I put together a spreadsheet comparing the parts in each.

Here is a Google Sheet with the part lists and the union of the sets: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1-bsj9zYrhTREDUyOfGJm83c2htyJIUeL408NDJd_jjM/edit?usp=sharing

Feel free to copy!

Answer (score 1):

Rebrickable has an option to compare two sets, MOCs or combination of both to see which parts are in common and unique to each of set/MOC.

[Here is a comparison results](https://rebrickable.com/sets/compare/slow/?1-set=45544-1&1-inv=11588&1-user_list=&2-set=31313-1&2-inv=14241&2-user_list=) between both EV3 Core and retail EV3 versions. You can also spot the "v1" for 31313 set, which means there is more than one inventory known for this set, so this is something you can [compare as well](https://rebrickable.com/sets/compare/slow/?1-set=31313-1&1-inv=14241&1-user_list=&2-set=31313-1&2-inv=32930&2-user_list=).